# How is an Angular app started without recompiling it?

Tags: angular

My first Angular app was both built and run by typing `ng serve` at the command line (then pressing Ent), which resulted in this:

```
10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 47.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 264 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 9.73 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.81 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-12-27T20:06:20.126Z - Hash: a1e99981ccb691148536 - Time: 5534ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

My question is:  Must that app be recompiled, as shown above, every time the app is served?

Comment: If you want the code to be bundled correctly, yes.

Comment: Will simply "ng build" bundle the code correctly, then index.html and its dependencies can be migrated to and started on any server, not just a node.js server?

Comment: You likely want to use "ng build -c production" and use the code in the dist folder for deployment. All of this is in [the documentation, by the way](https://angular.io/cli)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is not standard languages supported by web browsers, to run the TypeScript code it needs to get compiled first to JavaScript.

Also, Angular provides added syntax in HTML which is also not standard HTML, hence that needs to get compiled to standard HTML.

Due to this, any change in angular application results in recompiling. You may want to read JIT compilation in angular.

**After `ng build`**

After ng build, static files are generated, you can use this static files any way you want. You can host them with ngix, apache server or with spring boot project.

After static files generation there is no requirement of any dependency migration, as everything which is required is already bundled in static files.

Comment: Does "ng serve" create static files, or only "ng build" creates static files?  I've noticed more command line activity when using "ng build."

Comment: In both cases static files are generated, but there optimisation and creation in different in ng serve and ng build. In ng serve JIT compiler kicks in and in ng build AOT compiler kicks in.